# Realistic channel noise patterns

Tags: simulation, physics

I'm setting up a playful coding challenge for our programmers. It's about coding theory. There are source, channel and sink. The task will be to implement an encoder for the source and a decoder for the sink. The encoded information will be transmitted over a channel with simulated garbling.

Now my question:

**What common noise patterns do we encounter in real settings and how would their transformations look like?**

What people talk about are for example:

- band tapes (stressed at start and end)
- defect memory (some bits are always off)
- lightning strike
- meteor shower

But they never mention how these patterns would look like.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is there a way to move questions?

Comment: Mods will be happy to do that for you. Flag your own question and pick "in need of moderator intervention".

Comment: @dkaeae We can indeed migrate questions, and I will do so. However, note that it is usually better to just delete the question and re-ask on the other site if there are no useful answers or comments worth keeping. Migrations can lead to complicated situations (if e.g. electronics decides to close the question) and if there is no content worth moving beyond the question, I don't really see the point.